# Receiving message over JMS - WSO2 CEP

Tags: jms, wso2, complex-event-processing, wso2-cep

I have following questions - 
1. Does WSO2 CEP can listen to JMS queue also ? If yes, please share any article.
2. In case upstream application publishes message to topic and we have distributed (2 node CEP setup) CEP set up than shouldn't both node will process this JMS message and process duplicate message data ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when using JMS topics message duplication is a problem in CEP 2.0.1, you can fine a smiler question and a possible answer at [Distributed WSO2 CEP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452646/distributed-wso2-cep)