# Can WSO2 CEP 2.0.1 receive events from JMS queue?

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing

Like in jms-twitter example WSO2 CEP is receiving events from JMS Topic, I want to receive the events from JMS Queue . Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

We are not supporting for jms queue for CEP 2.1.0 also... we are planning to release this feature for CEP 3.0.0 (which is going to be release on 3rd quarter of 2013)...

Thanks,

Mohan

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in 2.0.1. Please follow this thread [Distributed WSO2 CEP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452646/distributed-wso2-cep) on how to achieve that in WSO2 CEP 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Upcoming release will support this.

Answer (score 0):

CEP 4.2.0 has been released last month. So you can use CEP 4.2.0 also. [Here](http://wso2.com/products/complex-event-processor/) is the link.
You can use Queue and topic in JMS in this version.